# Make one element visible depending on the value of another in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have three elements in my HTML, the Question, The Score, The Comment. The Score is an HTML SELECT, with "Poor", "Good" and "Excellent" as it's options.

I only want the Comment field to be visbile if the Score is ***not*** = "Good".

```
<!-- ko foreach: questions -->
  <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: question"></td>
      <td><select data-bind="options: availableScores"></select></td>
      <td>
         <!-- ko if: availableScores() != 'Good' -->
             <input data-bind="textInput: comment" />
         <!-- /ko -->
      </td>
  </tr>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the comment textbox must only be visible if the **selected** score differs from the value 'Good'.

For doing so, the selected value must be tracked and bound to the listbox,
here below via the property `selectedScore`.

A minimal MCVE shows this behaviour.

```js
var Question = function() {

  _self = this;
  _self.question = "";
  _self.comment = ko.observable("");
  _self.availableScores = ["Good", "Poor", "Excellent"];
  _self.selectedScore = ko.observable("Good");
}

var vm = new Question();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: availableScores, value: selectedScore"></select>
  
<!-- ko if: selectedScore() != 'Good' -->            
Comment: <input data-bind="textInput: comment" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: How would I make a collection of Question? My "survey" has 5 "Questions". My inclination is to change your Question function to an observableArray, but that negates the actions inside the function. (Probably not the best description, but I'm totally new to this whole javascript world)

Comment: You'll need a parent viewmodel (eg. Survey) containing an array of Question viewmodel instances, which you render in a loop. The cart and cartline example at http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html shows such a setup.

Answer (score 0):

how about you modify this line:

```
 <!-- ko if: availableScores() != 'Good' -->
```

to something like:

```
 <!-- ko if: displayComments() -->
```

and in your code add something like:

```
this.displayComments = ko.computed(function(){ return this.availableScores() !== 'Good'; });
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what the computed function returns. Depending on whether element #1 has a certain value, then element #2 must display or not display. I don't see how this function helps? The comment  is an input.

Comment: the point of my answer was that you should wrap logic in some function and not compare it in knockout html if, I also had some issues with it in past, I recall that there were even some issues with implementation of this **html if** structure and I had to wrap block I wanted to hide with div and use `data-bind`